# Travel to Oman from UAE by bus

Tags: customs-and-immigration, buses, uae, oman

My name is Rohit. I am now on a visit visa in UAE for 3 months, it will expire soon. Today I got Oman visit visa for 3 months. My question is that, is it possible to travel by bus from here UAE to Oman??
I Know it is possible for Residential visa holders to travel to Oman by bus, but don't know about for visit visa holders, my nationality is Indian.
Is there is any problem??

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, there are a lot of travel agencies in karama who arranged travel itinerary from Dubai to Oman on bus.